# How to install printer driver for HP Deskjet 1000 J110?

Tags: 10.04, installation, printing, hp

One printer has HP DJ 1000 J110 drivers installed and it works.

The other printer is another story that requires a little advice.

The main driver is `hplip-3.11.3a.run`. During its installation run (`sh hplip-3.11.3a.run`), it cuts off with the following error message:

```
error: Configure failed with error: General / Unknown error.
```

Why?

Lucid Repositories combed for HP and CUPS programs, , 'hp-setup', and hplip-3.11.3a.run but to no avail. Printer and computer connected together "localhost".

I added the ppa Andrea mentions but 'hp-setup' says `error: No devices found on bus: usb.` computer/printer is connected to localhost and the Document Print Status box says job is processing but there is no output.

And I cannot think of anything else to report at this point. Your help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a newly produced printer (that may require an updated hplip driver), I think that you can install hp-lip from the Softare Center..if you search for Hp, it should show you the hplip driver and you can install it from there without any problem..tha version is
3.10.2-2ubuntu2.2.. 
If it is a newly produced printer or if it doesn't work with the previous step, maybe you should try adding this ppa ppa:hplip-isv/ppa that installs the hplip version 3.11.1-0ubuntu2~ppa1..to make this write from the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hplip-isv/ppa
```

and then open the update manager and install the updates shown..

Comment: ppa added but 'hp-setup' says "error: No devices found on bus: usb."

Comment: No activity --- could not bring up Update Manager...could not install any updates.